# Reorganizing DataFrame (interchanging row information as columns)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have the next DataFrame.

```
data={
 'date':['2023-01', '2023-01', '2023-01', '2023-01', '2023-02', '2023-02', '2023-02', '2023-02', '2023-02'],
'concept':['FOOD', 'CAR', 'EDUCATION', 'ELECTRICITY', 'FOOD', 'CAR', 'TRAVEL', 'WATER', 'ELECTRICITY'],
'amount':[455.54, 237.41, 3.91, 213.2, 28.72, 422.72, 263.29, 3.93, 89.35]  
      }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I would like to reorder the information so I have all the concepts as rows, and then each column is a month. Finally a third column with the total sum of all months. The result should be a DataFrame like this:

|  | Jan-23 | Feb-23 | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CAR | 237.41 | 422.72 | 660.13 |
| EDUCATION | 3.91 | 0 | 3.91 |
| ELECTRICITY | 213.2 | 89.35 | 302.55 |
| FOOD | 455.54 | 28.72 | 484.26 |
| TRAVEL | 0 | 263.29 | 263.29 |
| WATER | 0 | 3.93 | 3.93 |

How could I do it?

Comment: I don't know about the additional column but every matrix-like structure should have a `transpose` function. I'd assume dataframes do too.

Comment: It's not a transpose, it's a [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `pivot` function like this and then use the sum function

```
new_df = df.pivot(columns='date', index='concept', values='amount')
new_df['total'] = new_df.sum(axis=1)
```

Comment: Also, `new_df.fillna(0)` to get the 0 values instead of NaN